# Non-repeating numbers in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have problem with my code, I want to find not repeated numbers in array but I don't know how!

```
1 2
3 4
1 4
```

For example in this case, I wan the output to be number 3 and 2:

I used this code for getting array, it's like a matrix

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        cam[i][j] = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

And something like this one for comparing for each one:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {            
    if (cam[i][2] != cam[i+1][2]) {
        y = cam[i+1][2];
        break;
    }            
}
```

Update: whole code is down below

```
int x=0,y=0;
int[][] cam = new int[10][10];

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        cam[i][j] = in.nextInt();
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {          
    if (cam[i][1] != cam[i+1][1]) {
        x = cam[i+1][1];
        break;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {            
    if (cam[i][2] != cam[i+1][2]) {
        y = cam[i+1][2];
        break;
    }            
}

System.out.println(x+" "+y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your code that you are looking only in column 1 and 2 (do you have other data in column 0?):

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    found = false;
    for (int i1 = i + 1; i1 <= 3; i1++) {
        if (cam[i][1] == cam[i1][1]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        x = cam[i][1];
    }
}
```

```java
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    found = false;
    for (int i1 = i + 1; i1 <= 3; i1++) {
        if (cam[i][2] == cam[i1][2]) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        y = cam[i][2];
    }
}
```

Comment: There are just two column , I started loop from 1

Answer (score 0):

Array indices are 0, 1, 2, ..., length-1.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < cam.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= cam[i].length; j++) {
        cam[i][j] = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

The search code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < cam.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= cam[i].length; j++) {
        int valueAtIJ = cam[i][j];
        boolean found = false;
        ... walk here through cam using valueAtIJ, set found, skip i, j.
        if (!found) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If alread Set/Map is treated in your course there are smarter solutions. But also this kind of for-i2-for-j2 loop can be optimized.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in map , but my most problem in coding is about the Array, and I'm trying to learn how it works!

Comment: Nice would be to make a method `boolean findFurtherOn(int i0, int j0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) a map of duplicates from this 2d array, then iterate over this map and apply [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) for non-repeating elements:

```java
int[][] arr = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {1, 4}};

Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Integer::intValue, Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(map); // {1=2, 2=1, 3=1, 4=2}

int[] arr2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [2, 3]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to find duplicate elements in array in effective way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65344781/14838237)</sup>